# How to write Custom flash message in react native

Tags: react-native, settimeout, flash-message

I want to display a custom message after successful record update when boolean value of recordUpdateSuccess become true and after 3seconds it should disappear.

```
{recordUpdateSuccess ? this.renderRecordUpdatedSucess() : null}
```

I have function to display message:

```
  renderRecordUpdatedSucess = () => (
    <View style={styles.sucessAlert}>
      <Text style={styles.sucessAlert}>Record updated successfully.</Text>
    </View>
  )
```

I tried to use setTimeout() to display message but not working.
Any idea to acheive this one.
I don't want to use Toast, any third party library for this one.

Comment: Show full component, are you sure that recordUpdateSuccess is true?

Comment: Add the full code, please!

Comment: @Borjante Yes recordUpdateSuccess true and display message but I want to disappear it after some second so i put setTimeout(()=>{ this.setState({recordUpdateSuccess: false}) },3000)

Comment: Full code please @RaviSharma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom flash message (No external Library)
Working Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/1dcddc

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     flashMessage: false
    }
  }

  onPress(){
    this.setState({
      flashMessage: true
    },()=>{setTimeout(() => this.closeFlashMessage(), 3000)})
  }

  closeFlashMessage(){
    this.setState({
      flashMessage: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.onPress()}}>
          <Text>Click Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
        {this.state.flashMessage==true?
          <View style={styles.flashMessage}>
          <Text style={{color:'white'}}>This is custom Flash message</Text>
        </View>
        :
        null
        }

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  flashMessage:{
    position:'absolute', 
    backgroundColor:'green', 
    width:'100%', 
    justifyContent:'center', 
    alignItems:'center',           
    height:40, 
    top:0
  }
});
```